# Colour fill all cells that match any date in a column

Tags: function, google-sheets, formula, gs-conditional-formatting, gs-vlookup

I would like green background fill to be applied to any cell - in entire sheet - whose date has a match in column C. I tried:

> =VLOOKUP(**A1**, C1:C15, 1)

but this works only for the specified "search key", A1, so I'd have to repeat the formula for each additional cell and there are way too many.

Perhaps this requires an Apps Script. Any Ideas?

Comment: This can be done with native conditional formatting. Are you looking for a match in column C, or C1:C15? Is it OK if the dates in C1:C15 are highlighted as well?

Comment: Also I think I answered what appears to be much the same question over here: https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!category-topic/docs/spreadsheets/jqgf-a5DyUs

Comment: The match can be throughout all of column C. Highlighting just for Column A.

Comment: See the sheet: http://j.mp/SheetFormattingTest

Comment: Yes, you can do this in Apps Script. But have you attempted any code at all? StackOverflow is a place for programming doubts, not just asking for programs.

Comment: Adam's suggestion over at the Google forum worked: =MATCH(A1,$C$1:$C$15,0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With VLOOKUP is possible, for example a Custom formula is:

```
=not(iserror(vlookup(A1,$C$1:$C$15,1,0)))
```

and Range: `A1:Z15`, or with the lookup range and Range extended to suit.